# Show item based on DOM index

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following scenario:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Show first div</li>
    <li>Show second div</li>
    <li>Show third div</li>
</ul>

<div id="boxes">
    <div style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
    <div style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
    <div style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
</div>
```

What I want is when the user clicks a `li` the corresponding `div` to be showed.

For now I'm doing it the following way:

```
$.("#menu li").click(function() {

    var position_clicked = $(this).index();

    $.("#boxes div:nth-child(" + (position_clicked + 1 ) + ")").show();

});
```

It is working fine, but I remember that there was an easier way of doing that just using some `nth-child` parameter on jQuery, something like:

```
// THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK!
// DO NOT COPY AND PASTE IT WITHOUT READING!
$.("#menu li:nth-child(n)").click(function() {

    $.("#boxes div:nth-child(n)").show();

});
```

How can it be done without that DOM position calculation?

Comment: Your original is the correct way of doing it. The 2nd way would require a separate click event for each one, which obviously is far worse than your original.

Comment: why you use nth-child? why do not use directly "#menu li" and "#boxes div" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$("#menu li").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#boxes div:eq('+index+')').show();

});
```

You can checkout my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/KQcAZ/

I updated the Fiddle just in case you want to hide the previous selection before showing the current one.